# The expression you entered contains invalid syntax

Tags: ms-access, vba

Sales: Sum([Order Details].Unit Price*[Order Details].Quantity)

When I tried to calculate this sum,I received the following error:

The expression you entered contains invalid syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this syntax: Sum([Order Details].[Unit Price]*[Order Details].Quantity)

the field name 'Unit Price' contains a space character and has to be enfolded with square brackets (like 'Order Details' already is)
and thanks for the welcome Toby :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term educational value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.